# differences between some concepts of Number Theoretic Transform (NTT)

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I'm researching on different variants of Number Theoretic Transform (NTT) and some concepts just got me confused.

1. What's the difference between Cooley-Tukey transform and Gentleman-Sande transform? My understanding is that both CT and GS transform are just a way to calculate NTT/INTT, so they may use different strategy to apply divide and conquer, their outputs however, should be the same. I see lots of implementation use both of them: they use CT for NTT and GS for INTT. So it's a bit confusing.
2. When you do NTT/INTT on module ring like $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N\pm1)$, you can also apply some technique like cyclic convolution (for mod $X^N-1$) or negative wrapped convolution (NWC-NTT, for mod $X^N+1$). What's the difference of them and why they apply to different quotient ring? What's the relationship between these two techniques with CT & GS butterflies?

Answer (score 0):

To the first question:

The GS butterfly can be seen as a reversing of the CT butterfly, this can be a side answer to this question(why use CT in NTT, and GS in INTT?).

The CT butterfly can be represented as
$$
a' = a + b \zeta
$$
$$
b' = a - b \zeta
$$

therefore, in the INTT phase, the GS butterfly can be used to get
$$
a = (a'+b') * 2^{-1}
$$
$$
b = (a'-b') * \zeta^{-1} * 2^{-1}
$$

take the $* 2^{-1}$ away, it is the original GS butterfly.

To the second question:

The cyclic convolution is also named as "positive wrapped convolution (PWC)", The $\mod X^n+1(-1)$ means $X^n = -1(1)$, which is origin of the "negtive (positive)".
An example:

$$
2x^2 * 3x^4 = 6x^6 = -6x \mod x^5 + 1
$$

The NWC and PWC donot have relationship with CT & GS.